# Override Default Tabbing Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, tabindex

I am trying to use jquery to override the default tabbing navigation.  I cannot simply use the tabindex property because I am trying to get the tab key to navigate from a text input to a virtualized textbox (codemirror).  I have been trying to use the following javascript/jquery to no avail:

```
$('#modelName').focus(function() { 
    $(this).keydown( function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode=='9') {
            codeMirror.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: Try `event.which` instead of keyCode.

Comment: `event.which === 9` no quotes. jQuery normalizes `which`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $('#modelName').keydown( function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
        codeMirror.focus();
    }else{
        alert("Not the right key! " + event.keyCode);   
    }
  });
```

It's good to have a catch, just so you can see where you're going wrong.
In this case, I think it's string vs int.

Also, the way your code is, you would be applying a new `keydown` event handler each time the `#modelName` gets focus, without removing the old one. Would likely cause problems later.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  The event.preventDefault() did it.

Comment: If my answer fixed it, and you're happy, then keep the community going by accepting this as your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it told me to wait a minute and I forgot to come back to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#modelName').keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode== 9){
    codeMirror.focus();
    }
});
```

use keyup() instead of keydown()

Comment: `keydown` would feel more right if you were trying to mimic general tab behaviour. Also, `keyCode` 27 is the `esc` key...